# OS X Terminal Tab Name Current Directory Causes Duplicate Name in Title Bar

Tags: macos, terminal

In OS X (10.9.3) I'm setting PROMPT_COMMAND to set the terminal tab name to the current directory such as

```
function set_tab_title {
  printf "\e]0;${PWD##*/}\a"
}

PROMPT_COMMAND="set_tab_title; $PROMPT_COMMAND"
```

I added the `$PROMPT_COMMAND` to make sure I still keep the behavior of opening new tabs in the current working directory. The problem now is that the tab window shows the folder name twice. Screenshot below. Any ideas why this is?
[image]

Comment: Same here. I think it's because both the existing print from `update_terminal_cwd()` in the default `$PROMPT_COMMAND` and the override for title bar are outputting the directory.

Perhaps there's a way to set the current directory without outputting the directory?